# Subtract/compare differences between two audio files using Python

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, librosa

My goal is to take two identical length .wav files, one original with noise + speech, one processed with improved speech and compare the two. This should leave me with the difference of the two wave files being the noise that was removed during the processing.

I would like to do this to practice my python coding skills, also to test the efficiency of speech processing programs. So far I have found programs that can do this but I would really like to build my own simple version in python. Some libraries that I have considered are [audiodiff](https://audiodiff.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [librosa](https://github.com/librosa/librosa) but it doesn't seem like they include a subtract function.

I have a few programs that can accomplish this but I would like to create a simple version and be able to customize it over time as my needs expand.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the way to ask on SO :-)

Comment: if you found some programs then you should add links in question (not in comment)

Comment: For a given short time window, check what frequencies are in the speech-only file. Use spectral subtraction to attenuate all other frequencies in the corresponding time window in the noise + speech file.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You might want to ask this on Data Science stack exchange instead. As a programming question it is a bit lacking in details

Answer (score 1):

The task of estimating the quality of a speech clip is known as *Speech Quality Estimation*. A slightly simpler task formulation is *Speech Intelligibility*, which only measures how easy it is to understand the speech, not the subjective "quality" of the speech signal.
These are established task within speech signal processing, and there are industry standards as well as bleeding edge research. Such methods (often referred to as objective metrics) take into account the human auditory system and perception of speech in order to give a good estimate for how a group of humans would evaluate the result in a listening test. Because of the complexity of human perception, good methods are a bit more involved than just a difference of the audio.

If you have access to the original speech (without noise), then you can use a full reference based method. An early ITU standard is [PESQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_Evaluation_of_Speech_Quality), and the most recent as of 2021 is [POLQA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_Objective_Listening_Quality_Analysis). A good metric with open source implementation is [VISQOL](https://github.com/google/visqol).

If you do not have access to the original speech without noise, you must use a no-reference / single-ended / non-intrusive method. An ITU standard is [P.563](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-P.563/en). There is currently a lot of research using deep neural networks to better solve this task. Examples are [NISQA](https://github.com/gabrielmittag/NISQA), [Gamper2019](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/intrusive-and-non-intrusive-perceptual-speech-quality-assessment-using-a-convolutional-neural-network/)

Some more details can be found on https://github.com/jonnor/machinehearing/tree/master/audio-quality